# Mapbox Navigation android Repo cloned and not able to run facing debug compile error of Plugins

Tags: java, git, gradle, navigation, mapbox-android

1. Mapbox Navigation SDK version:

   #### Steps to trigger behavior

   ```
    1.Clone the Mapbox Android Navigation .
    2.Add  Username and Access Token key in project gradle propoerties
    3.Add Authentication in project modue gradle file
   ```

   #### Expected behavior Project should sync and when run app should run in device

   #### Actual behavior Facing debug compile errors:-

   ```
   ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':carbon@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
   com.mapbox.maps:android:10.0.0-alpha.5.
   Show Details
   Affected Modules: carbon

   Project Gradle Code:-
   >apply plugin: 'com.github.kt3k.coveralls'
   apply plugin: 'jacoco'

   buildscript {
     apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/dependencies.gradle"

     repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()
       maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2' }
       maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
     }
     dependencies {
       classpath pluginDependencies.gradle
       classpath pluginDependencies.kotlin
       classpath pluginDependencies.coveralls
       classpath pluginDependencies.errorprone
       classpath pluginDependencies.dependencyUpdates
       classpath pluginDependencies.jacoco
       classpath pluginDependencies.playPublisher
       classpath pluginDependencies.googleServices
       classpath pluginDependencies.crashlytics
       classpath pluginDependencies.license
       classpath pluginDependencies.mapboxSdkVersions
       classpath pluginDependencies.mavenPublish
       classpath pluginDependencies.bintray
       classpath pluginDependencies.artifactory
       classpath pluginDependencies.dokka
     }
   }

   task testReport(type: TestReport, group: 'Build') {
     description = 'Generates an aggregate test report'
     destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/reports/allTests")
   }

   allprojects {
     repositories {
       maven {
         url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v1/navigation/android/maven'
         authentication {
           basic(BasicAuthentication)
         }
         credentials {
           username = project.properties['username'] ?: ""
           password = project.properties['access_token'] ?: ""
         }
       }
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()
       maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2' }
       //    maven {
       //      url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
       //      authentication {
       //        basic(BasicAuthentication)
       //      }
       //      credentials {
       //        username = "mapbox"
       //        password = project.hasProperty('SDK_REGISTRY_TOKEN') ? project.property('SDK_REGISTRY_TOKEN') :
       System.getenv('SDK_REGISTRY_TOKEN')
       //      }
       //    }
       maven {
         url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox_internal'
         credentials {
           username = project.hasProperty('BINTRAY_USER') ? project.property('BINTRAY_USER') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
           password = project.hasProperty('BINTRAY_API_KEY') ? project.property('BINTRAY_API_KEY') :
      System.getenv('BINTRAY_API_KEY')
         }
       }
       maven {
         url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox_collab'
         credentials {
           username = project.hasProperty('BINTRAY_USER') ? project.property('BINTRAY_USER') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
           password = project.hasProperty('BINTRAY_API_KEY') ? project.property('BINTRAY_API_KEY') :
       System.getenv('BINTRAY_API_KEY')
         }
       }
       maven {
         url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox_private'
         credentials {
           username = project.hasProperty('BINTRAY_USER') ? project.property('BINTRAY_USER') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
           password = project.hasProperty('BINTRAY_API_KEY') ? project.property('BINTRAY_API_KEY') :
       System.getenv('BINTRAY_API_KEY')
         }
       }
       maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
       maven { url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/' }
     }

     group = GROUP
     version = VERSION_NAME
   }

   subprojects {
     apply plugin: 'idea'
     apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.errorprone'
     apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/dependencies.gradle"

     dependencies {
       errorprone dependenciesList.errorprone
     }

     plugins.withId('org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm') {
       compileKotlin {
         kotlinOptions {
           jvmTarget = "1.8"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   #### Project Module Code

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
   apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
   apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/script-git-version.gradle"
   apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/ktlint.gradle"

   android {
     compileSdkVersion androidVersions.compileSdkVersion

     compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }

     playConfigs {
       defaultAccountConfig {
         serviceAccountCredentials = file("$project.rootDir/android-gl-native- 
       15d95ab30d0f.json")
       }
     }

     def getGitHash = { ->
       try {
         def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
         exec {
           commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
           standardOutput = stdout
         }
         return stdout.toString().trim()
       } catch (Exception exception) {
         return ""
       }
     }

     defaultConfig {
         applicationId   "com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.app"
         `enter code here`minSdkVersion androidVersions.minSdkVersion
       targetSdkVersion androidVersions.targetSdkVersion
       multiDexEnabled true
       versionCode gitVersionCode
       versionName gitVersionName
       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       buildConfigField "String", "GIT_HASH", "\"${getGitHash()}\""
     }

     signingConfigs {
       release {
         keyAlias System.getenv("CIRCLECI_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
         keyPassword System.getenv("CIRCLECI_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD")
         storeFile file("$project.rootDir/navigation_testapp.keystore")
         storePassword System.getenv("CIRCLECI_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
       }
     }

     buildTypes {
       debug {
         testCoverageEnabled = false
         manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting:"false"]
       }
       release {
         minifyEnabled true
         signingConfig signingConfigs.release
         manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting:"true"]
       }
     }

     dexOptions {
       maxProcessCount 8
       javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
       preDexLibraries true
     }

     lintOptions {
       abortOnError false
     }

     play {
       serviceAccountCredentials = playConfigs.defaultAccountConfig.serviceAccountCredentials
       track = System.getenv("GOOGLE_PLAY_TRACK") ?: "internal"
     }
   }

   dependencies {
     //ktlint
     ktlint dependenciesList.ktlint

     // Kotlin support
     implementation dependenciesList.kotlinStdLib
     implementation dependenciesList.ankoCommon
     //  implementation 'com.mapbox.navigation:core:1.0.0-rc.2'
     // Mapbox Navigation SDK
     implementation project(':libandroid-navigation-ui')
     implementation dependenciesList.mapboxMapSdk
     implementation dependenciesList.mapboxSearchSdk
     implementation dependenciesList.mapboxCrashMonitor

     // Support libraries
     implementation dependenciesList.androidXAppCompat
     implementation dependenciesList.materialDesign
     implementation dependenciesList.androidXRecyclerView
     implementation dependenciesList.androidXConstraintLayout
     implementation dependenciesList.androidXCardView
     implementation dependenciesList.lifecycleExtensions

     implementation dependenciesList.gmsLocation

     implementation dependenciesList.firebaseCore
     implementation dependenciesList.crashlytics

     implementation dependenciesList.multidex

     // Logging
     implementation dependenciesList.timber

     // Network
     implementation(dependenciesList.okhttp) {
       force = true
     }
     implementation(dependenciesList.okhttpInterceptor) {
       force = true
     }

     // Butter Knife
     implementation dependenciesList.butterKnife
     annotationProcessor dependenciesList.butterKnifeProcessor

     // Leak Canary
     debugImplementation dependenciesList.leakCanaryDebug

     // Unit Testing
     testImplementation dependenciesList.junit
     testImplementation dependenciesList.mockito
     testImplementation dependenciesList.mockk

     // Instrumentation testing
     androidTestImplementation dependenciesList.testRules
     androidTestImplementation(dependenciesList.testEspressoCore, {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
     androidTestImplementation dependenciesList.testEspressoContrib
   }

   apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/developer-config.gradle"
   apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/checkstyle.gradle"
   apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/dependency-updates.gradle"


   Projrct gradle.properties Code:-


   > VERSION_NAME=0.43.0-SNAPSHOT
   GROUP=com.mapbox.mapboxsdk

   POM_URL=https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android
   POM_SCM_URL=https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android
   POM_SCM_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android.git
   POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android.git

   POM_LICENCE_NAME=The MIT License
   POM_LICENCE_URL=https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
   POM_LICENCE_DIST=repo

   POM_DEVELOPER_ID=mapbox
   POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Mapbox

   POM_UI_SNAPSHOT_VERSION_NAME=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
   POM_CORE_SNAPSHOT_VERSION_NAME=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

   MAPBOX_USERNAME=harshit999
   MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN="sktoken here"
   ```